# Image won't open from response object using PIL in google Colaboratory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I am going through the "PyTorch for Deep Learning and Computer Vision" course on Udemy and inputting the code into Google Colaboratory as instructed.

However, there a part of the code where PIL is meant to read an image from a response object, but I have an error "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

I am using pillow 4.0.0 on python 3.6
I have tried changing resonse.raw to response.content, response.text, and just response. I have tried removing the stream = True attribute and I have tried inputting the url directly into the Image.open method

```py
!pip3 install pillow==4.0.0

import PIL.ImageOps

import requests
from PIL import Image

url = 'https://c8.alamy.com/comp/DYC06A/hornless-reindeer-at-zoo-DYC06A.jpg'
response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
img = Image.open(response.raw)
plt.imshow(img)
```

I expect a plot with an image of a deer with the url in the url variable.

Instead I receive this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-85-059526041234> in <module>()
      4 url = 'https://c8.alamy.com/comp/DYC06A/hornless-reindeer-at-zoo-DYC06A.jpg'
      5 response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
----> 6 img = Image.open(response.raw)
      7 plt.imshow(img)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py in jpeg_factory(fp, filename)
    750 # Factory for making JPEG and MPO instances
    751 def jpeg_factory(fp=None, filename=None):
--> 752     im = JpegImageFile(fp, filename)
    753     try:
    754         mpheader = im._getmp()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in __init__(self, fp, filename)
     95 
     96         try:
---> 97             self._open()
     98         except (IndexError,  # end of data
     99                 TypeError,  # end of data (ord)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py in _open(self)
    321                 # print(hex(i), name, description)
    322                 if handler is not None:
--> 323                     handler(self, i)
    324                 if i == 0xFFDA:  # start of scan
    325                     rawmode = self.mode

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py in SOF(self, marker)
    144     n = i16(self.fp.read(2))-2
    145     s = ImageFile._safe_read(self.fp, n)
--> 146     self.size = i16(s[3:]), i16(s[1:])
    147 
    148     self.bits = i8(s[0])

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Works on Pillow 6.0.0 & Python 3.7. Consider updating the package: `pip install Pillow -U`

Comment: Where would I insert the package update?

Comment: Your code starts with a `pip` statement, try replacing that with mine and run it. Make sure it starts with `!`

Comment: It worked. I tried updating it before, but I ignored the "restart runtime message". This time I didn't and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading pillow solved this for me

```
pip install pillow --upgrade
```